# Bayes' theorem assumptions (using continuous distributions)

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, bayes-theorem

I have computed $\frac{g(y\mid x)f(x)}{g(y)}$, where $g(y\mid x)$, $f(x)$, and $g(y)$ are density functions (i.e. they integrate to 1 and the functions are always $\geq0$).

What assumptions must I make to conclude that this fraction is equal to $f(x\mid y)$? Since the resulting distribution doesn't integrate to 1 (not even close), it seems as if I'm missing some unknown assumption....

Does the fact that $g(y)$ is only positive when $y\subseteq[0,1]$ have any special relevance? (Note $f(x)>0$ for all $x$).

Comment: Why do you say that it does not integrate to 1?  Are you trying to integrate over the $x$ variable or the $y$ variable?  Note that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X|Y}(x|y)dx = 1$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Assuming $g_{Y|X}(y|x) = \frac{f_{XY}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$ then indeed we integrate to 1.

Comment: I computed the fraction (on R), and just by plotting it it's clear that the area under the curve is substantially greater than 1. It may also be relevant that unconditional y is Unif~[0,1] so g(y) = 1. I don't know the joint density, but g(y)=1 implies f(x|y) is equal to the joint density...

Comment: What is it, exactly, that you are plotting?  It seems there is a lot hidden, so it is not clear how to answer your question.